# WebApi Test Stres ASYNC .NET CORE

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, web-api-testing

I am trying to develop my first web api in .NET Core, from what I understand I need to use async/await when I am dealing with database transactions. I made a stress test on a a sync version and on the async version of the same method and the results on the async methods are awful compared with the ones on the sync method and I honestly can't understand why, maybe I am doing something wrong so I would really appreciate your help. I will leave the the methods and the test results.

--Async Method

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Employer>> Get()
        {
            return await context.Employer.ToListAsync();
        }
```

[image: Async method test results]
--Sync Method --

```
[HttpGet]
    public  IEnumerable<Employer> Get()
    {
        return  context.Employer.ToList();
    }
```

[image: Sync method test result]

Comment: You don't need to use async/await just because you're using "database transactions." There's a lot more to async/await than working with a database. I'm still not intimately familiar with async/await, so I don't have a solid answer (hence the comment instead).